# RecyclerView with reverseLayout starts in scrolled position when height is set to match constraints

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

I have a recycler view with

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomBar"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/topBar"
```

and

```
LinearLayoutManager(this.context).apply {
  reverseLayout = true
}
```

But when I load data into, it starts scrolled up a bit from the bottom (specifically, scrolled up exactly as many pixels as the height of `bottomBar` + `topBar`)

If I set the height to a fixed value, this doesn't happen.
If I set `reverseLayout = false`, this doesn't happen.
If I set the visibility of `topBar` and `bottomBar` to `GONE`, this doesn't happen.
`recyclerView.scrollToPosition(0)` is not a valid solution because it will interfere with restoring scroll state

I've found a bug report with the same issue, but no replies from google.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/243702056

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out through trial and error that setting the `topBar` height to `wrap_content` instead of `0dp` fixes it.

I do not understand why